# MUX in iVerilog: Unable to bind parameter/cannot evaluate genvar expression errors

Tags: verilog, mux, iverilog

Will someone please take a look at my code and explain why I am getting these errors. I am brand new to iverilog. This is for a project

`Power_ALU.v:13 error: Unable to bind parameter 'select' in 'Power_ALU_tb.ALU8'`

`Power_ALU.v:13 error: Cannot evaluate genvar conditional expression: (select)==('sd0)`

Line 13 is the first line under //INCREMENT

Here is my code

```
module PowerALU(Out,Cin,s1,s2,s3,A,B);

input [7:0] A,B;
input Cin,s1,s2,s3;
output [7:0] Out;

wire Cout,A_LT_B,A_GT_B,A_EQ_B;
wire [7:0] Sum,And,Or,Xor,Nand,Nor,Xnor;
wire select;
assign select = {s3,s2,s1,Cin};

//INCREMENT
if(select == 0)
begin
    assign B = 8'b00000001;
    RCA8 rca1(Cout,Sum,A,B,Cin);
    assign Out = Sum;
end
//TRANSFER
.
.
.
//EQ
else if(select == 14)
begin
    Comparator8 comp3(A_GT_B,A_LT_B,A_EQ_B,A,B);
    assign Out = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,A_EQ_B};
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `if` statement outside of an `always` (or `initial`) block, it is interpreted as a generate-if used for selecting different hardware to create at build time. As a result, if the condition is not an elaboration time constant, as here, then the result is a compile error.

You should put your `if` statements inside an `always @*` block and remove the `assign` keyword from the assignments. You will need to move the submodule instances outside of the `always` block, they can't be turned on or off at runtime.